# How to make force-pushed branch the tip in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

My initial situation is similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015557/forgetting-a-dead-end-branch). Coming from a strong Git background, I wanted to force-push a cleaned-up version of my private branch (under the same name) where I've squashed / folded some commits (using the [histedit extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension)). What I did again is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11016218/1127485), but I did things in a different order:

```
$ hg clone -b private_branch <url>
$ hg histedit -r <some_rev> # Fold some commits
$ hg push -f # This creates a second branch head on the server
$ hg update -r <rev_of_original_branch_head>
$ hg commit --close-branch -m 'Closing this branch in favor of a cleaned-up version'
$ hg push
```

The thing I don't understand is, if I now set up a new working tree, I get

```
$ hg clone -b private_branch <url>
$ hg log -l 1
changeset:   <rev>:<sha1>
branch:      private_branch
tag:         tip
parent:      <tip_rev_of_branch_before_folding>:<sha1>
user:        <name> <email>
date:        Wed Aug 08 11:48:25 2012 +0200
summary:     Closing this branch in favor of a cleaned-up version
```

Why is `tip` pointing to the closed branch? `hg heads` is only showing my force-pushed head as expected. However, `hg heads -t` is showing both heads for `private_branch`. I've also verified that my closing commit is indeed a closing one, `hg log --debug` shows `extra: close=1`.

**EDIT:** The problem with this is, if I do a commit on a fresh clone, I get

```
$ hg ci -m "test"
created new head
reopening closed branch head <rev>
```

But I do not want to reopen the closed branch head, I want to commit on top of the open branch head.

How can I fix this, preferably without doing a [no-op merge](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PruningDeadBranches#No-Op_Merges)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to simply do

```
$ hg update private_branch
```

to set the working directory's parent revision as shown by `hg parent(s)` to the newly created open branch head, away from the closed branch head. It was somewhat unintuitive to me that I needed to "switch branches" although I already "am on that branch", but in this case I was not switching branches, but switching heads within a single branch. Something that works completely different than in Git.

Answer (score 1):

> The tip tag is a special “floating” tag, which always identifies the
>   newest revision in the repository.

(from http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-releases-and-branchy-development.html)

That's why `tip` points to a revision involving the closed branch.

Is there actually a problem here? If you just carry on working you'll be on `private_branch` with the changes you wanted to be made.

Comment: The problem is, if I do a commit on a fresh clone, it will reopen the closed branch. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for clearing me up on what exactly `tip` points to, however!

Comment: I would call that a bug with `-b`.  I just tested that if the default branch has two heads and the most recent one is closed, cloning without `-b default` will update to the older open head, not the closed tip. But add `-b default` to the clone and it updates to the more recent closed head.  Running an additional `hg update default` selects the older open head again.